# Converting CGPoint to GLKVector2 in Objective-C

Tags: ios, xcode

Simple question. What is the best way to turn a CGPoint into a GLKVector?

These structures are identical so it would be nice to be able to reinterpret_cast or memcpy or something like that. My solution below works but hardly seems optimum. I'm creating a GLKVector2 on the stack assigning each member then returning this as a value which is then assigned to another GLKVector.

It's not going to break the bank or anything but there must be a neater way to do this?

```
GLKVector2 Vector2FromPoint(CGPoint point)
{
    GLKVector2 v;
    v.x = point.x;
    v.y = point.y;
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Your way of doing it is the only possible way that I found on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using memcpy in a function like this:

```
bool vector2ToCGPoint(GLKVector2* s, CGPoint* d) {
    memcpy(d, s, sizeof(*d));
}
```

but then it is probably better to have:

```
bool copyVector2ToCGPoint(GLKVector2* s, CGPoint* d) {
     d.x = s.x;
     d.y = s.x;
}
```

if you really want optimization, you could go for a macro:

```
#define copyS2D(S,D) (D.x = S.x, D.y = S.y)
```

so you can do:

```
CGPoint b;
GLKVector2 a;
vector2FromCGPoint(a, b);
```

of course, as you know, macros will not be that much type-safe...

Comment: (Apologies for the formatting I can't work it out and haven't the tim right now)  
THanks for the answers. Here is another way: Cast to void ptr then to a GLKVector. 
  
'#define GLKVectorMakeFromCGPoint(p) (GLKVector2)(void*)(&p)'  
  
This is dangerous because 1. it's a macro 2. You have to be 100% that these structures are identical. Still should work. – David John

Comment: Sorry missed a * there should be:  
`GLKVector2 myVec2 = *(GLKVector2*)((void*)&myCGPoint);` or  

 '#define GLKVectorMakeFromCGPoint(p) **(GLKVector2)(void*)(&p)'

Comment: You should not cast between the types. GLKVector2 specifies a byte alignment of 8, which is not specified for CGPoint. This is to speed up NEON instructions performed on matrices and vectors. Casting will cause the NEON operations to perform slower.

Answer (score -1):

```
GLKVector2 v = GLKVector2Make(point.x, point.y);
```