# No more GLKMatrix4 in Swift?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, swift, opengl-es-2.0, xcode6

I need GLKMatrix4 for implement model view projection in my swift framework project,

but I can not find the class, what should I do with swift ?

Comment: Have you tried to add `import GLKit` ?

Comment: yes, I did, but there is no more GLKMatrix4 in "Swift"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using GLKMath from GLKit in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622475/using-glkmath-from-glkit-in-swift)