# GLKQuaternion in Swift

Tags: swift, glkit, myo

Trying to re-write Objective-C code written for the [Myo](https://developer.thalmic.com/) I came across the GLKQuaternion class which is a union and doesn't seem to be supported in Swift ([Using GLKMath from GLKit in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622475/using-glkmath-from-glkit-in-swift)).

What I am looking for is a workaround to get this to work. Maybe a hybrid application with Math being done in ObjectiveC so I can access those properties. What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using a bridge file and creating a small wrapper layer to allow me access to the data I wanted from Swift. I called it a polyfill, similar to what we had on the web to enhance capabilities of old browsers.

The [code is available on github](https://github.com/yagudaev/HelloMyoSwift). Particularly [this commit](https://github.com/yagudaev/HelloMyoSwift/commit/5b4f6d88fb5052639426f26e03efe66c18061756#diff-dc01683cf1165da929df9ee44f129fe6R1) will be of interest as it shows what needs to be done.

**Polyfill.h**

```
@interface OrientationData: NSObject
  @property (nonatomic) TLMAngle *pitch;
  @property (nonatomic) TLMAngle *yaw;
  @property (nonatomic) TLMAngle *roll;
@end

@implementation OrientationData
@end

@interface GLKitPolyfill: NSObject
+ (OrientationData *) getOrientation:(TLMOrientationEvent *)orientationEvent;
@end
```

**Polyfill.m**

```
+ (OrientationData *) getOrientation:(TLMOrientationEvent *)orientationEvent {
  TLMEulerAngles *angles = [TLMEulerAngles anglesWithQuaternion:orientationEvent.quaternion];

  OrientationData *result = [OrientationData new];
  result.pitch = angles.pitch;
  result.yaw = angles.yaw;
  result.roll = angles.roll;

  return result;
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
let angles = GLKitPolyfill.getOrientation(orientationEvent)
let pitch = CGFloat(angles.pitch.radians)
let yaw = CGFloat(angles.yaw.radians)
let roll = CGFloat(angles.roll.radians)
```

[Apples Mix & Match guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html) gives good tips on how to make Obj-C work with Swift and vice-versa.

Comment: The Myo iOS SDK has been updated to not use GLKit anymore (in order to make it more compatible with Swift).